# how to fix a pizza order calculation code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Finally I have made a most of the code work, but still run into the issue with subtotal and adding the toppings to subtotal. When I choose the size of pizza, it shows the price of pizza in subtotal(correct); it shows pst and gst as a +7% of subtotal(correct); it shows its total(correct~~~). It doesn't do anything (not adding 0.50 per topping to subtotal) when I select the toppings.
How to fix it?
[image]

```
const priceSmall = 4.00;
const priceMedium = 5.00;
const priceLarge = 7.00;
const priceToppings = 0.50; 
const pst = .07;
const gst = .07
let subtotal = 0;
let toppingPrice = 0;

function calculateSize(element) {
  if (element == null) {
    return;
  }

  switch(element.value) {
    case "10":
      subtotal = priceSmall;
      break;
    case "12":
      subtotal = priceMedium;
      break;
    case "15":
      subtotal = priceLarge;
      break;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}

function toppingOptionPrice(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
      toppingPrice += priceToppings;
  } else {
      toppingPrice -= priceToppings;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}

function recalculateTotal() {
  let pstToPay = subtotal * pst;
  let gstToPay = subtotal * gst;
  let total = subtotal + pstToPay + gstToPay;
  document.getElementById("subtotal").value = subtotal;
  document.getElementById("pstToPay").value = pstToPay;
  document.getElementById("gstToPay").value = gstToPay;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="media/pizza-served.jpg" width="600" height="277" alt="Pizza Logo"/>
        <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
    </header>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="http://lavalamp.dyndns.org/~mult114/pizzaorder_olympic.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="difficulty" value="1" />
            <fieldset id="contactinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Contact Information</strong></legend>
                    <label for="firstnameinput">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstnameinput" name="FirstName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="lastnameinput">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastnameinput" name="LastName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="addrinput">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="addrinput" name="Address_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="phoneinput">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinput" name="Phone_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="emailinput">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailinput" name="Email_tf" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="orderinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order</strong></legend>
                <fieldset id="pizzasize">
                    <legend>Pizza Size</legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="smallsize" name="Size_rg" value="10" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                        <label for="smallsize">Small 10"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="mediumsize" name="Size_rg" value="12" onclick="calculateSize(this);">  
                        <label for="mediumsize">Medium 12"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="largesize" name="Size_rg" value="15" onclick="calculateSize(this);"> 
                        <label for="largesize">Large 15"</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="toppingbox">
                    <legend>Topping(s)</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="anchovies" name="Anchovies_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="anchovies">Anchovies</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="doublecheese" name="DoubleCheese_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="doublecheese">Double Cheese</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="Pepperoni_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mushrooms" name="Mushroom_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="mushrooms">Mushrooms</label><br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="instructions">
                    <legend>Special Instructions</legend>
                        <textarea id="textarea" name="instructions" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here!(special requests, delivery details, etc.)"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="payments">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Payment</strong></legend>
                <label>Select Payment Method:</label>
                    <select id="paymethods" name="Payment_menu" required="required">
                        <option value="select">- Select One -</option>
                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                        <option value="debit">Debit</option>
                        <option value="credit">Credit Card</option>
                     </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="calcprice">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order Total</strong></legend>
                    <label for="subtotal">SubTotal $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="SubTotal_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="pstToPay">PST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pstToPay" name="PST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="gstToPay">GST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="gstToPay" name="GST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="total">Total $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="total" name="Total_tb" readonly><br>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit_but">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post html in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is okay with your code. Actually I like it, its nice. The checkboxes are not changing the `subtotal` value because you are not updating it on the `toppingOptionPrice()` function. I removed `let toppingPrice = 0` and replaced the `toppingPrice` variable for the `subtotal` variable inside `toppingOptionPrice()` function. And it's working.

```js
const priceSmall = 4.00;
const priceMedium = 5.00;
const priceLarge = 7.00;
const priceToppings = 0.50; 
const pst = .07;
const gst = .07
let subtotal = 0;

function calculateSize(element) {
  if (element == null) {
    return;
  }

  switch(element.value) {
    case "10":
      subtotal = priceSmall;
      break;
    case "12":
      subtotal = priceMedium;
      break;
    case "15":
      subtotal = priceLarge;
      break;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}

function toppingOptionPrice(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
      subtotal += priceToppings;
  } else {
      subtotal -= priceToppings;
  }
    recalculateTotal();
}

function recalculateTotal() {
  let pstToPay = subtotal * pst;
  let gstToPay = subtotal * gst;
  let total = subtotal + pstToPay + gstToPay;
  document.getElementById("subtotal").value = subtotal;
  document.getElementById("pstToPay").value = pstToPay;
  document.getElementById("gstToPay").value = gstToPay;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="media/pizza-served.jpg" width="600" height="277" alt="Pizza Logo"/>
        <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
    </header>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="http://lavalamp.dyndns.org/~mult114/pizzaorder_olympic.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="difficulty" value="1" />
            <fieldset id="contactinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Contact Information</strong></legend>
                    <label for="firstnameinput">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstnameinput" name="FirstName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="lastnameinput">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastnameinput" name="LastName_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="addrinput">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="addrinput" name="Address_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="phoneinput">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinput" name="Phone_tf" /><br>
                    <label for="emailinput">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailinput" name="Email_tf" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="orderinfo">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order</strong></legend>
                <fieldset id="pizzasize">
                    <legend>Pizza Size</legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="smallsize" name="Size_rg" value="10" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                        <label for="smallsize">Small 10"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="mediumsize" name="Size_rg" value="12" onclick="calculateSize(this);">  
                        <label for="mediumsize">Medium 12"</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="largesize" name="Size_rg" value="15" onclick="calculateSize(this);"> 
                        <label for="largesize">Large 15"</label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="toppingbox">
                    <legend>Topping(s)</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="anchovies" name="Anchovies_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="anchovies">Anchovies</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="doublecheese" name="DoubleCheese_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="doublecheese">Double Cheese</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="Pepperoni_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mushrooms" name="Mushroom_cb" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                        <label for="mushrooms">Mushrooms</label><br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="instructions">
                    <legend>Special Instructions</legend>
                        <textarea id="textarea" name="instructions" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here!(special requests, delivery details, etc.)"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="payments">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Payment</strong></legend>
                <label>Select Payment Method:</label>
                    <select id="paymethods" name="Payment_menu" required="required">
                        <option value="select">- Select One -</option>
                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                        <option value="debit">Debit</option>
                        <option value="credit">Credit Card</option>
                     </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="calcprice">
                <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order Total</strong></legend>
                    <label for="subtotal">SubTotal $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="SubTotal_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="pstToPay">PST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pstToPay" name="PST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="gstToPay">GST $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="gstToPay" name="GST_tb" readonly><br>
                    <label for="total">Total $:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="total" name="Total_tb" readonly><br>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit_but">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is working just perfect..thanks a lot.. spent like a couple of hours figuring out what was wrong